# SQL insert into ... select from doesn't work because of trigger update

Tags: mysql, sql

**EDIT** I don't have CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE permissions. Is there another way?

A MySQL database has a table `User` which contains an `id` column.

Another table is `UserThing` which has a `user` column which is a foreign key to `User.id`

I am trying to insert one row into `UserThing` for certain rows in `User`, like this.

```
INSERT INTO `UserThing` (`user`, `foo`, `bar`)
SELECT `id`, 123, 456 FROM `User` WHERE some_condition;
```

I'm pretty sure this is okay except that there is a trigger on `UserThing` which potentially updates a column in `User`. This creates a dependency loop which MySql doesn't allow, although I know that this trigger's action is orthogonal to `some_condition` so it doesn't matter in practice.

I know I can write `SELECT @some_var := ...` for single values, but I can't make it work for multiple values. Is a local variable the right way to fix this? If so, what is the syntax, please? If not, is there some other pure-SQL way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried your syntax?  My understanding is that the `select` is executed first and then the `update`, meaning that the trigger will not interfere with the data.

Comment: Yeah: `#1442 - Can't update table 'User' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.`

Comment: @spraff - Check this out - http://crazytoon.com/2008/03/03/mysql-error-1442- hy000-cant-update-table-t1-in-stored-functiontrigger-because-it-is-already-used-by-statement-which-invoked-this-stored-functiontrigger/

Answer (score 0):

I would use a temporary table and break them `INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM` into the following statements:

```
SELECT `id`, 123, 456 INTO #tmp FROM `User` WHERE some_condition;

INSERT INTO `UserThing` (`user`, `foo`, `bar`)
SELECT * FROM #tmp

DROP TABLE #tmp
```

Comment: I can't create temporary tables on this server.

Comment: Also, what's with the hash syntax? It's not in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

Comment: Ah! seems the # syntax to refer to temporary tables is specific to SQL Server. The syntax for creating temporary tables in MySQL is similar to that of `CREATE TABLE` except saying `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`.